# Удаление сообщений через VkNet. Бот вк

Tags: c#, vknet

Всем привет, пишу бота
при попытке удалить сообщение ранее написанное ботом получаю ошибку:

One of the parameters specified was missing or invalid: message_ids or cmids is undefined"

И вроде понятно что значит, но cmids не является параметром функции. Соответственно я даже не знаю как мне работать с ним. Документация ответов не дает. https://vk.com/dev/messages.delete

C#

```
List<ulong> idMessages = new(); 
idMessages.Add((ulong)SendMessag("1"));
Thread.Sleep(10000);
IEnumerable<ulong> enumerable = idMessages.AsEnumerable();
_bot.Api.Messages.Delete(messageIds: enumerable);
 
 
private static long SendMessag(string message)
{           
    return _bot.Api.Messages.Send(new MessagesSendParams()
    {
        Message = message,
        PeerId = 2000000002, 
        RandomId = Environment.TickCount
    });
}
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Сообщения для удаления отправляете, а от куда удалять где? `peer_id` например, или `group_id`. Поиграйтесь с параметрами.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Вообще messageIds не зависит от диалога и тому подобного... Однако его нельзя использовать в ботах

Comment: Попробуйте использовать peer_id и cmdi (ConservationMessageIds)